# Add value to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

while training a deep learning model I would like to keep track of all the metrics I am interested in in a dataframe. Therefore, I have a dataframe that is made that way:

```
import pandas as pd
df_results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['loss', 'val_loss', 'val_accuracy'])
```

however I would like to append at each epoch a new row with the values, something like

```
df_results += [0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
```

How can I actually do that?

Comment: Which deep learning library are using? The most common APIs already have a method or function that do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the append function in the Pandas. This can be done as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df_results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['loss', 'val_loss', 'val_accuracy'])
df_results = df_results.append({'loss':0.1, 'val_loss':0.1, 'val_accuracy':0.1}, ignore_index = True)
df_results = df_results.append({'loss':0.2, 'val_loss':0.3, 'val_accuracy':0.4}, ignore_index = True)
print(df_results)
```

I hope this resolves your problem.